# Asp.Net MVC - MySQL - Saving Č get converted to C, why?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, special-characters

Using Aps.Net MVC 5, .NET 4.5, Entity Framework 5, MySQL database, table is in utf8_general_ci.
Saving Š,š,đ,Đ,Ž,ž works fine. But Č,č,Ć,ć converts to C,c

Comment: It might be relevant that characters Š,š,đ,Đ,Ž,ž are representable in the windows-1252 encoding but Č,č,Ć,ć are not.

Comment: Found it, in the connection string of the EntityFramework, i needed to add Charset=utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, in the connection string of the EntityFramework, i needed to add Charset=utf8